# Duplicate column for faster queries?

Tags: database-design, normalization

The title doesn't make too much sense, but I couldn't think a better title for this problem.

I have the following tables

**Projects**

- id
- name

**Customers**

- id
- id_project
- name

**Payments**

- id
- id_customer
- date
- sum

When a users enters the system, he will have access to a certain project. Now, I want to list all the payments for that project, and it should be pretty easy:

```
SELECT FROM payments where id_customer in (SELECT id from customers where id_project = 5)
```

My question is : if it isn't better to add a column id_project to payments table this way the queries will be easier and faster.

Comment: so query is not a problem for modern RDBMSes (or better, use join).

Comment: Agree, get a query plan for subselect vs join and see which one is better

Comment: I think this [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001543/in-vs-join-with-large-rowsets) post is worth looking, since @igor mentioned about using JOIN or IN

Answer (score 65, accepted):

It seems you are asking if [denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization) makes sense.

> Denormalization is the process of attempting to optimize the read performance of a database by adding redundant data or by grouping data. In some cases, denormalization helps cover up the inefficiencies inherent in relational database software. A relational normalized database imposes a heavy access load over physical storage of data even if it is well tuned for high performance.

The answer is always "it depends", so here's my rule of thumb:

If ...

- the amount of data is not large
- you aren't doing a ton of joins already
- and/or database performance is not currently a bottleneck

then *stay normalized*. Yes, denormalization is faster, but it also means you have redundant data in the system -- data that has to be maintained and kept in sync. There is no longer "one source" for that data, but multiple sources that can deviate. This is risky over time, so you shouldn't do it unless you have very good reasons to do it, backed by some benchmarks.

I would only denormalize when ...

- the amount of data is very large
- joins are expensive and you have to do a lot of them to get even trivial queries returned
- database performance is a bottleneck and/or you want to go *as fast as possible*

Joins are very fast on modern hardware, but they are *never* free.

Answer (score 10):

You would be better to rewrite the query as:

```
SELECT payments.*
FROM   customers
JOIN   payments 
ON     payments.id_customer = customers.id
WHERE  customers.id_project = 5
```

While this seems less concise and a good query planner will see what you are trying to do and run your correlated sub-query as the above join instead, a bad query planner may end up doing an index scan of `payments.id_customer` (assuming you have a relevant index) (or worse, table scanning) instead of doing things the more efficient way. Even a good query planner may fail to see the optimisation if the arrangement of this query is wrapped in something more complicated. Expressing the relationship as a join rather than a sub-query may make more difference than changing your data structure.

As Jeff says, any denormalising should be considered with care - it can bring easy performance boosts, particularly for some reporting purposes, but can lead to inconsistency due to bugs in the supporting business logic.

As a side note: Obviously I don't know your business so I could be missing something, but your table relationships seem odd to me. They imply that you can never have more than one project with the same customer which is usually not true in my experience, at least over a long period.

```
customer     project      payment
--------     --------     -------
                          pa_id
             pr_id    <-- payment
cu_id    <-- customer
```

or if being less normalised (though I doubt that would be necessary):

```
customer     project      payment
--------     --------     --------
                          pa_id
             pr_id    <-- payment
cu_id    <-- customer 
           `------------- customer
```

Of course that still discounts the possibility of a joint project with two customers...

Comment: First rule of performance: Never use * in production!

Comment: @Brian: very valid point. And as well as the potential performance implications avoiding * in select clauses also avoids problems with column ordering in views-on-view in MSSQL if sys.depends gets out of kilter due to `DROP VIEW`+`CREATE VIEW` being used instead of `ALTER VIEW`.

Comment: @Brian i put * for easy of writing.

Comment: The project is a thought more as a independent application with its on domain and belongs to different customers so a customer cannot cannot have the same account on different projects

Answer (score 6):

In some databases you have the possibility to create "Materialized Views" instead of complex VIEWS with a large amount of data, based on a complex query.This can be used to avoid denormalization in a historical grown application system.If you decide to use "Materialized Views" you have to have a clear idea of refresh methods and the amount of storage which will be used by the Materialized View...